# website for open source/royalty free android controls

Tags: android, controls

I'm looking for a website similar to [Custom UI Controls for iOS and Mac OS X](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

Which hosts/source some amazin iOS controls, but for the android platform.

I've seen a couple of questions like this, but none have been posted/update
in a couple of years.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent Web site, as of the time of this writing. Two of the larger link collections for reusable Android components, including custom widgets, are:

- http://www.openintents.org/en/libraries
- http://www.theultimateandroidlibrary.com/

Note that not everything on these sites is necessarily "open source/royalty free".